# Problems with Room on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

**So, i want to create a button on Android Studio that updates my list in a sorting order, Ascending, etc., but i've been running in to some problems with the code and i can wrap my head around it. When i click the button nothing happends, it doesn't sort my list at all**

**Using Room Database FrameWork from Andriod Studio.**

**This is what i using to do the sorting:**

---

```
 //'Produto' is the list, 'nome' is a element on that list that i want to sort
 @Entity 
 @Parcelize 
 data class Produto(
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 val id: Long,      
 val nome: String)


@Query("SELECT * FROM Produto") 
    fun buscaTodos() : List<Produto>

//This is the code that i use to do the sorting
@Query("SELECT * FROM Produto ORDER BY nome ASC")
    fun getAllSortedByName(): List<Produto>
```

---

**This is the code to i'm using to do the sorting after a press the button**

```
     class ListaProdutosAdapter(
         private val context: Context,
         produtos: List<Produto> = emptyList(),
         var quandoClicaNoItem: (produto: Produto) -> Unit = {}
      ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaProdutosAdapter.ViewHolder>() {



    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    private val adapter = ListaProdutosAdapter(context = this) 
    val db = AppDatabase.instancia(this)
    val produtoDao = db.produtoDao()

    //menu_ordem_asc_id being the button id
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_ordem_asc_id -> {
            produto?.let { produtoDao.getAllSortedByName()}
            adapter.atualiza(produtoDao.buscaTodos())

            //This is in another class, but i put it here so it's easier to understand
            fun atualiza(produtos: List<Produto>) {
                this.produtos.clear()
                this.produtos.addAll(produtos)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            } 
            
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question though ? what's working or what isn't working ?

Comment: So basicly the app opens up fine everything else works fine as well, but when i press the button to do the sorting nothing happends, i want to know whats wrong with it, is it more clear now?

Comment: What does buscaTodos() do? What is produto? Also you're not doing anything with the result of getAllSortedByName(). The sorted items are returned as a List<Produto> but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: @RazvanS. @Query("SELECT * FROM Produto")
                   fun buscaTodos() : List<Produto>

Comment: ```@Entity```
```@Parcelize```
data class Produto(
        ```@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)```
        val id: Long = 0L,
        val nome: String,
        val descricao: String,
        val valor: BigDecimal,
        val imagem: String? = null
) : Parcelable

Comment: Also what can i do with the getAllSortedByName() to get the result that i want?, i don't get what you mean't by i'm not doing anything with the value returned, if you could give me an exemple of what to do would help alot. ( I'm sorry for the lack of details, this is my first question on this website, so i don't know what so say exacly )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `produtoDao.getAllSortedByName()` doesn't sort the items in place, it returns a list of sorted items. So when you do  `produto?.let { produtoDao.getAllSortedByName()}` you don't do anything with the result which is the sorted list.

On the next line you call `adapter.atualiza(produtoDao.buscaTodos())` and as you mentioned in your comments `produtoDao.buscaTodos()` returns an unsorted list of products. And this is what you populate your adapter with.

In order to populate the adapter with the sorted list you should call `adapter.atualiza(produtoDao.getAllSortedByName())` instead.

Comment: Your solution worked, but after you told me this i think the problem is somewhere else, you see, i don't want to create another list, i want to sort the list that already exist, the buscaTodos() to be more exact, how can i do that?

Comment: Well that's the way you can get data out of the Room DB, in List form that is.  If you only need it in sorted order you can delete the getAllSortedByName code from everywhere and add  the @Query("SELECT * FROM Produto ORDER BY nome ASC") query to buscaTodos() instead of its current query.

Comment: I tried that it didn't really worked the way i wanted, so i will stay to the you told me, thanks that helped a lot.